# Raspberry pi 3B+ HDMI audio truncated

Tags: pi-3, audio-playback

Ruuning NOOBS. I can set the default audio to HDMI out, attach an audio extractor to the HDMI, and get sound out. Except, with two different brands of audio extractors so far, it's common for the first few milliseconds - I'm guesstimating up to 100ms - of the audio to be dropped, for any given sound sample. Even just "aplay x.wav x.wav x.wav" exhibits the problem.

You may think losing the first few ms wouldn't matter, but it does. A lot. Especially if the sound sample is maybe 150ms long to begin with.

If this a known problem and is there a solution? If no one knows what I'm talking about, maybe it's the sound extractors I'm using. If you extract audio from HDMI and never dropped a single cycle, let me know what extractor you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your /boot/config.txt:

```
force_hdmi_open=1
```